# Exercise index (Pike pushups first or regular ones)

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, push-ups, programs

I don’t know which exercise should I do the first Pike pushups or regular pushups. I heard that you should start with the hardest exercise, which is pike pu for me but also I heard that you should start with compound exercises first, and pushups are more compound than pike pu.

Comment: Starting with the "hardest exercise" only makes sense if the exercises explicitly target the same muscles; while there's obviously some overlap here, pikes are more focused on the shoulders/tris than regular pushups (which also can hit tris depending on arm position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say pike pushups first is likely ideal because these are callisthenic movements.

Compound first is typically something people say to people lifting weights. You don't want to do isolation work and tire out a muscle required in a lift or the rest of the muscles required in the lift won't get as much out of the session. Worst case scenario you tire out muscles required to maintain proper form in the lift and get injured.

Hardest first is something typically taught in calisthenics. This is because if you don't do it at the start of the workout, you probably won't be able to do that progression at all. Also, as Dave mentioned in the comments, this is taught because a lot of callisthenic moves have overlap in the muscles they use and virtually everything is compound.

The way I structure my workouts is one of the big three lifts first always. Bench, deadlift, and squat before anything. Next I prioritize the most difficult callisthenic movements going to the least difficult. I finish my workouts with isolation work for muscles I missed/want a bit more volume on.

Comment: Does this also apply to pullups and front lever raises, since the latter is more difficult than pullups?

Comment: Yeah, I never do pullups before I train my front lever. In calisthenics the general rule is to do your hardest progressions first.